# the point of using a webhook secret

Tags: heroku, webhooks

For a heroku app, I have a webhook for "api:release".

Even if I set a secret for the webhook, my webhook app still receives the hook.

So what's the point of setting the optional secret ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Anyone can hit your webhook and trigger your build because it's a HTTP endpoint with no authentication. To prevent scripts/abusers starting a massive amount of builds the secret can be used.

When receiving the webhook the sender has to include a token, this token can be validated by comparing it to the secret. If the tokens match it is same to assume that a valid client send it. If the token doesn't match uo you can ignore the request and thus prevent an unnecessary build that was initiated from an untrusted source.

More details about setting up the secrets: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/app-webhooks#step-3-subscribe

To compare the checksum you can use the following snippet:

```
crypto.createHmac('sha256', '12345').update(Buffer.from(req.rawBody)).digest('base64');
```

and compare it with the `Heroku-Webhook-Hmac-SHA256` header value.

Comment: Thanks !  Now I'm trying to understand how to validate the secret sent, against the "heroku-webhook-hmac-sha256" header's value. If anyone can help...

Comment: You did receive the secret when executing the following command: `heroku webhooks:add ...` you can compare the value of that secret agains the value of the `Heroku-Webhook-Hmac-SHA256` header. @trogne

Comment: I don't think it's that easy. I've tried with a custom secret "12345", but the `Heroku-Webhook-Hmac-SHA256` value always changes, e.g. "XAYmo9fOondiBwOx+ZIyC+3Z+wuZ7B6UWBd3T//1VH8="...  So I guess I have to built a value (how?!?) based on the request and "12345", and compare that value to `Heroku-Webhook-Hmac-SHA256`.   Ex. here for Ruby on Rails : https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/app-webhooks#securing-webhook-requests  . How to do that with Node.js ?

Comment: You can use the `hash_hmac` function like this: `$checksum = hash_hmac('sha256', $incomingWebhookData, '12345');` And comparing the `$checksum with the header value`@trogne

Comment: Great !  And I did it that way : First of all, get the raw body, using bodyParser.raw, then calculating the hash using the crypto library : `crypto.createHmac('sha256', '12345').update(Buffer.from(req.rawBody)).digest('base64');` ,  and comparing the result with the header.  You can post an answer, and I will accept it.  THANKS!

Answer (score 0):

For ruby users working with `rack`, you'll do something like

```rb
OpenSSL::HMAC.digest('SHA256', key, body) == Base64.decode64(request.env['Heroku-Webhook-Hmac-SHA256'])
```